# iterate on file inside a folder

Tags: java, file

i found this solution to iterate files inside a folder,but it gave me `nullpointException`

```
import java.io.File;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    File path = new File("/resources/subFolder"); 
    File [] files = path.listFiles(); -> line of nullPointExpection
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
        if (files[i].isFile()){ 
            System.out.println(files[i]);
        }
    }
}
}
```

this folder is inside an eclipse project.

```
project
  -src
  -resources
    -subFolder
      -file1
      -file2

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

any suggest to resolve it?

Comment: Have you tried adding the fully qualified path instead of relative path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NPE is caused by `/resources/subFolder` not existing.

The problem is the leading `/` in `/resources/subFolder`. This means an absolute path, i.e. relative to the root of your filesystem. You should remove it to make it a relative path, i.e. `resources/subFolder`.

A good idea would be to use `File.exists()` before the loop.

Comment: the subfolder directory exists in my project,it still give me a nullpoint with your edits @Roberto

Answer (score 0):

The javadoc from File.listFiles() says:

```
 * @return  An array of abstract pathnames denoting the files and
 *          directories in the directory denoted by this abstract pathname.
 *          The array will be empty if the directory is empty.  Returns
 *          {@code null} if this abstract pathname does not denote a
 *          directory, or if an I/O error occurs.
```

So I would assume directory does not exists, most likely because of the preceding '/' character in path, which basically means it starts searching from the root of the drive, i.e. using absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your path from:

```
File path = new File("/resources/subFolder");
```

to

```
File path = new File("resources/subFolder");
```

or perhaps

```
File path = new File("../resources/subFolder");
```

Depending on your configuration.

Your code with the added suggestion from @Roberto runs without any nullpointerexception

```
import java.io.File;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File path = new File("/home/sander"); 
        if(path.exists()) {
            File [] files = path.listFiles(); 
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            if (files[i].isFile()){ 
                System.out.println(files[i]);
            }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Path doesn't exist");
        }
    }
}
```

If this doesn't work for you, perhaps it could it be a file permissions issue (unlikely as it may seem).

Comment: the subfolder directory exists in my project,and the folder has 2 files inside it.

Comment: I ran your code and it listed the files as expected. So there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code. I've also added the if(path.Exists()) {  } check suggested by @Roberto. Now I don't even get an exception with an non existing path.

Comment: i tried to print `path.listFiles()` it is null, why is it right for you?

Answer (score 0):

If

```
File [] files = path.listFiles()
```

returns `NullPointerException` it means that `path` object is `null`. It means that

```
File path = new File("/resources/subFolder");
```

created `null` object what is quite abnormal situation in Java. Check if line number 9 refers to the line you provided. I guess that `NullPointerException` is caused by the loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
```

because you don't have files in given directory or your path is incorrect as Roberto subbested.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {

        java.net.URL dirURL = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("resources");
        File[] filePaths = new File(dirURL.toURI()).listFiles();
        for (File file : filePaths) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                System.out.println(file);
            }
        }

    }
}
```